# What would happen if Superman was bitten by a vampire?

Tags: dc, superman, vampire

Does being bit by a vampire affect Superman?
If yes, how, and to what extent?
If no, then why?

Comment: Does the vampire have kryptonite teeth?

Comment: I am considering vampire ultra powerful...Twilight grade powerful...super fast and strong, with very sharp and strong teeth... I guess at the very least they could bit as hard as a fly does to a normal human being!

Comment: @JohnP Well, considering that Superman *has* been bitten by vampires, it has a definitive answer.

Comment: I agree. Since it has demonstrably occurred, we can ask the question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### [Superman has faced off against vampires on a number of occasions, and bested them because he is <s>immune to magic</s> Superman.](http://ifanboy.com/articles/dc-histories-superman-vs-vampires/)

He was in fact was once bitten by Dracula. But because the Man of Steel is fueled by the sun, Dracula immediately exploded.

> [image]

However, quite recently he had another run in with Dracula:

> while Superman’s blood was inedible, sucking it did allow Crucifer to gain control over the Man of Steel. Crucifer now had a Kryptonian bodyguard who did anything that was asked of him.
> [image]
> [image]

But again, he was able to break free, before breaking Dracula.

> [image]

Comment: Dracula had some kryptonite? How was he able to pierce Superman's skin?

Comment: Not so sure if I am getting it right but  what your saying is about the effect of Superman on a vampire...not about the effect of a vampire venom on superman

Comment: Well it seems that the venom has no effect, as Superman is immune, or fights it off quite quickly.

Comment: I'm no expect, but I though Superman was *vulnerable* to magic.... am I wrong?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'm with you on this one. I'm pretty sure Superman's only real weakness aside from Kryptonite is to magic. He definitely is not immune to it. Also the pictures in the answer don't mention magic at all

Comment: @thePopMachine you are right, I knew there was something against magic. Either way, he's faced vampires and won, and not been turned.

Comment: I see we were using the same source - you answered while I was still typing :)

Comment: Superman is vulnerable to magic. This is common canon knowledge, from comics to Smallville.

Comment: @asma22 Why, what does this not answer?  Does Superman become a vampire?  No.  Does he briefly lose control of himself?  Yes.  Can he break free?  Yes.  What's left?

Comment: @MishaRosnach asma22 commented that before the edit. the answer is much better now

Comment: The second vampire seems to be named Crucifer, not Dracula – or is this later revealed as the same person?

Answer (score 14):

It has happened before - check [Superman vs vampires](http://ifanboy.com/articles/dc-histories-superman-vs-vampires/) It was in times when vampires were great dark anti-heroes not sparkling fanservice teenagers.

First of all vampire CAN bite superman because magic. By that I mean vampires have magic powers which is strong enough to go through Man of Steel bullet-proof skin.
Now, depending from the story:

- Dracula bit into Superman but melted, because Superman is solar powered
- Crucifier found his blood disgusting, but was able to mind control him

Judging from those two cases I believe that either Superman simply cannot be turned undead or he will be immediately turned into ash because his reliability on sun energy

Comment: I know that Twilight deserves all the scorn it gets, especially for the "sparkling" thing, but there've been [teenage vampire heroes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095684/) long before that (1987, in this case)...

Comment: To be fair, great dark anti-heroes are *also* fanservice, it's merely a question of whose taste you're servicing ;-) For that matter Lucy Westenra was a teen vampire, wasn't she?